# Timeout on a NamedPipe in C#

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I have a couple of apps talking to each other, and I use a NamedPipe. But if the other app isn't available then the NamedPipe waits for ever to connect. It also doesn't support timeouts.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Are you using the [NamedPipeClientStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.aspx) class?  If so there is an overload of [Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355337.aspx) which takes a timeout value.  That will allow you to specify how long you wait before giving up.

Comment: Did you mean NamedPipeClientStream?